# I can not seem to get my 'Form.TopMost = true' to work

Tags: winforms

I am trying to connect a checkbox to change 'Form.TopMost'. 
Everytime I use the Form.TopMost i get the following error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 
'System.Windows.Forms.Form.TopMost.get' 
N:\VisualStudio\Projects\SpriteProject\YoutubeOverlay\Browser.cs    23  13  
YoutubeOverlay
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: post code plz, this should be easy to answer

Comment: My colleague has found the problem. fix = 'this.Topmost'

Comment: a little tip, since you are obviously very new to programming. check the microsoft documentation, there are always code samples that are easy to understand

Answer (score 2):

If you are changing the property in the code behind of the form, you should use:

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: When I set it to `this.TopMost = false` my form still stays on top :/

Comment: Your problem probably deserves its own question. As a comment to an unrelated question, it lacks enough context for an answer.

Comment: @madd0... I was able to figure it out. It was with IF/ELSE statement. works now. Thanks. I Upvoted the answer because it helped.